# Is GetHashCode of Protobuf the same everywhere?

Tags: hash, protocol-buffers

I noticed I have `GetHashCode()` in my generated C# class from `.proto` file. To make tampering with data more difficult I want to calculate the hash code send it together with the data. Then I can compute the hash again at the destination.

My approach is to have a hash field in the proto definition, but prior to computing the hash I will left it 0, compute it, put it in and serialize. At the destination the hash will be remembered, make it 0, and then compute the new hash to check the integrity.

On the receiving end is JavaScript :

- Will the hash generation function at the destination produces the same result?
- If `.proto` file got updated with new fields, new class generated everywhere, will the old message hash to the same result?

I know about MD5, but I think it needs to be generated after the binary file is complete, and I cannot include the MD5 together with the data if I do that.

I will still have an encryption on top of this, but just in case someone manages to decrypt the data he could not easily change some part of it to fool the receiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use `GetHashCode()` like that. It isn't a protobuf concept, but rather exists for all .NET managed types. Firstly, it is not the case that every object overrides this method, and if it doesn't, then for a class it represents the **reference/instance**, not the contents (just like `Equals` does by default). If it is overridden, then it is expected to produce the same value each time **in the same app-domain**, but there is no requirement for it to produce the same value in different runs. Whether it does depends on the implementation and the exact framework you are using (assuming things like `string.GetHashCode` are used).

But the other problem is that the code in the **target framework** would have no matching method, and even if it did: would not have access to the same implementations of things like `string.GetHashCode`.

So no: don't use this for that purpose. It doesn't do that.

As a specific example: things like `string.GetHashCode` produce different values for the same string **depending on the OS and .NET version**. It wouldn't even do what you want purely on .NET endpoints.

As a trivial example, consider:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("abc".GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine("abc".GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine("abc".GetHashCode());
}
```

If I run this once, I get:

```
518228267
518228267
518228267
```

So you might think "ah, yes, `GetHashCode()` gives the same value each time". However, it is more subtle than that. On recent versions of .NET, this is seeded *at app-startup*, so if I run it again I get:

```
-177712234
-177712234
-177712234
```

then

```
-59760352
-59760352
-59760352
```

etc. This was done in part to avoid people depending on `GetHashCode()` being the same between runs, and in part to prevent people being able to use sets of strings known to have the same hash-code as an attack vector to put stress on dictionaries (forcing them to use fallback behaviour) - for example as DDOS attacks against web-servers. If the hash can't be predicted by static external code, this attack vector goes away.